# How would I speed up this JSON request process?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Apologies if this is too abstract.

I using mainly jQuery to create a Chrome extension where users can subscribe to feeds. A 'random' selection of items from these feeds are then delivered on the user's new tab page.

Here's the process I'm planning to use. Is this the fastest way of doing it?

1. Check which feeds the user is subscribed to and use nested `$.getJSON` requests to bring them in.
2. Cache these locally for at least the next 12 hours so they can be quickly retrieved again.
3. Convert the feeds to JSON objects and combine using `concat`.
4. Shuffle the items in this new, single, combined feed.
5. Load the first 36 results (and display using Masonry).
6. Add an infinite scroll that loads blocks of 36 results when the user scrolls down.

On top of this, I also intend to cache the JSON feeds on the server for 12 hours or so.

Is this the quickest way of going about it? Might it be faster to swap steps 2 and 3 around given that it's not very frequent that a user will subscribe to more feeds?

As the emphasis is on loading speed, there's plenty else I'm happy to sacrifice. For example, it doesn't have to be JSON I use if a database would be better. Similarly, the caching can be for a long period of time because the objects the user is being shown will be in a 'random' order and so needn't be the latest.

Comment: Show us some specific code and we can help you tune that code; but there are just too many moving parts with this question to be able to authoritatively answer all parts of it.

Comment: One question – why randomise post-fetch and not pre-fetch?

Comment: @Ashesh - surely I need something to randomise? Or are you suggesting I swap steps 3 and 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do most of this on the server side and only send the 36 required feeds, which should load very fast depending on their content.

Your biggest bottlenecks are the following:

- Fetching the various feeds (~1 second per feed)
- Building a list of those feeds for a specific user
- Downloading the feeds to the user's browser

The last two are not terribly long, but the difference between loading 36 presorted items and organizing an arbitrary number of random elements is important when the new tab page is only used for a few seconds.

The easiest solution is to fetch all feeds on the server, put them in a database and retrieve the last 36 matches for the users that need them. This has several advantages:

- Fetching from a database takes milliseconds. Fetching a feed from a remote page can take a few seconds.
- Databases are made to be queried, so fetching, merging and sorting results is easy.
- The short, pre-filtered list of items will download far faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was planning on using JavaScript's local storage for storing the subscription details - would this require that I used a database? Doing it in PHP would be much quicker for me because I'm stronger with it than JS.

Comment: What is your infrastructure exactly? You left out many details, but I assumed in my answer that you managed subscriptions on a remote server, and fetched feeds from arbitrary sources.

Comment: So my feeds are on my server - each contains scraped data from a particular website in JSON format. I intend for subscriptions to be managed using local storage but a proper database might not be a bad idea.

Comment: The fastest way to do it would be to store the feed elements as individual items on the server (as database records), then to build custom feeds on demand for each user. I will edit my answer.

Comment: That looks great, thank you! One thing - because my front end has to be JS (as it's a Chrome extension), will doing this with AJAX requests slow things down dramatically or will it still be fast?

Comment: Oh, and final thing - will this require me setting up a crontab to deal with periodically adding to the database or am I better off with another method?

Comment: An AJAX request is a request like any other. There is the usual request/response delay, but no special overhead that would bog you down.

Comment: Thanks for your help - definitely set me on a better track than before!